# Nuxt.js – script using document working in the whole project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

for my CSS framework customization needs I'm using a script for an onClick button "pulse effect". Currently I run it in mounted() part of my default.vue layout in Nuxt.js project running in SSR mode.

This is the script:

```
if (process.client) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault;
      this.classList.remove("pulse");
      void this.offsetWidth;
      this.classList.add("pulse");
    });
  }
}
```

It's an easy script and it's working well but only on reload and only for some buttons which are on the top of my page's DOM.

When I copy-paste this script into a component's script part, it's working in the component well. But I do not want to include it into every component.

Where in my project should I add it to make it working in all components? I've tried to add it into the nuxt-config but it did not work.

Please help.

Comment: why dont you create a custom global vue directive?

Comment: I do not have any experience with this. Could you guide me a bit, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a plugin that do that stuff for you you need to go to `nuxt.config.js`

```
plugins: ['~/plugins/pulse.js']
```

Now you go to your plugins folder and create that pulse.js and write in

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.directive('pulse', {
  inserted: (el) => {
    el.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault;
      el.classList.remove("pulse");
      void el.offsetWidth;
      el.classList.add("pulse");
    });
  }
})
```

After that your directive is global and you can go to any button you want and add simply `v-pulse` to it

```
<button v-pulse>Click me</button>
```

Tell me if it works and if you receive any errors.

Comment: Sounds great, but what if I don't want to set it in all my buttons manually and just want to listen to the click event? I think that a directive will not work. Ive tried with a Mixin but it is not working for me.